# Пространство для контактов/данных в amoCRM

Tags: amocrm

Что делать если лимит контактов/данных в amoCRM превышен. Можно ли докупить пространство. Если можно, то эта докупка она будет постоянно на аккаунте или после продления лицензии нужно будет заново увеличивать лимиты?

Answer (score 0):

Для решения проблемы можно перейти на более дорогой тариф amoCRM "Профессиональный", в нем больше лимит по контактам - 20 000 контактов. Можно докупить аккаунты пользователей, на каждого пользователя увеличивается дополнительно лимит контактов. Выгодней взять более дорогой тариф, но если контактов очень много возможно придется делать и то и другое. Ну а также хорошо проверить контакты на дубли и удалить дубли чтоб за них не платить.